# Node js stream with array

Tags: node.js, firebase, stream, algolia

First time using node streams and I am trying to stream an array to Algolia. The Algolia provided example uses a json file. https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/sending-and-managing-data/send-and-update-your-data/how-to/sending-records-in-batches/?language=javascript#example

I tried to stringify the array and then use it like the Algolia example describes. I'm not sure what the best way is to accomplish this. Should I be stringifying the array, or do I need to iterate over the array and push it into the stream? Does the latter approach still use fs? This will run on firebase functions, so there is a resource constraint.

```
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch')
const fs = require('fs');
const StreamArray = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray');

const client = algoliasearch('999999', '999999');
//const index = client.initIndex('d_DASH');
const index = client.initIndex('t_DASH');



exports.dashStream = async function (listings) {
    let jsdoc = JSON.stringify(listings);
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(jsdoc).pipe(StreamArray.withParser());


    let chunks = [];
    stream
        .on('data', ({ value }) => {
            console.log("on data...")
            chunks.push(value);
            if (chunks.length === 10000) {
                stream.pause();
                index
                    .saveObjects(chunks)
                    .then(res => {
                        chunks = [];
                        stream.resume();
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.error(err));
            }
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log("on end...")
            if (chunks.length) {
                console.log(`stream over?`)
                index.saveObjects(chunks,function (err, content){
                    return content.taskID.toString();
                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err));
            }
        })
        .on('error', err => console.error(err));
}
```

The code needs to complete the write to Algolia and return the taskID from the Algolia response.

Comment: Consider using `for await` instead of the silly "data"/"end" dance which creates some confusing code :]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too late but maybe it will help somebody else.
I would suggest using additional streams and pipelines

### buffer.stream.ts

Stream that will collect your data into chunks and push them to writing stream

```
import { Transform } from "stream";

// Using transform stream to collect your data into chunks
export class BufferStream extends Transform {
  private readonly buffer: object[] = [];

  constructor() {
    super({ objectMode: true });
  }

  _transform(data: object, _encoding: string, callback: () => void) {
    this.buffer.push(data);
    // You chunk size goes here. I find myself usually using a 1000
    if (this.buffer.length >= 3) {
      // Handling back pressure if push() returns false
      if (this.push(this.buffer.splice(0))) {
        callback();
      } else {
        this._read = () => {
          delete this._read;
          callback();
        };
      }
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }

  _final(callback: () => void) {
    // Pushing leftovers
    this.push(this.buffer);
    callback();
  }
}
```

### write.stream.ts

Stream that will handle writing to your destination

> You have to be extra careful when using asynchronous callbacks with streams

```
import { Writable } from 'stream';

export class WriteStream extends Writable {
  constructor() {
    super({ objectMode: true });
  }

  async _write(chunk: object[], _encoding: string, callback: () => void) {
    // You have to handle your errors yourself in an asynchronous callback
    try {
      // await save(chunk);
      console.log('Chunk:', chunk)
      callback();
    } catch (error) {
      // nextTick to escape current stack
      process.nextTick(() => this.emit('error', error));
    }
  }
}
```

### Glueing it all together

```
import stream, { PassThrough } from "stream";
import { promisify } from "util";
import { BufferStream } from "./buffer.stream";
import { WriteStream } from "./write.stream";

const pipelineAsync = promisify(stream.pipeline);

(async () => {
  // Imitating a stream with some data
  const stream = new PassThrough({ objectMode: true });
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    stream.push(i);
  }
  stream.end();

  await pipelineAsync(stream, new BufferStream(), new WriteStream());
})();
```

### Output

```
Chunk: [ 0, 1, 2 ]
Chunk: [ 3, 4, 5 ]
Chunk: [ 6, 7, 8 ]
Chunk: [ 9 ] <-- Last chunk
```

From my experience it handles backpressure by itself. You don't need to call stream.pause() and .resume(). And overall subjectively it looks cleaner